# get selected option from dropdown using php (the dropdown has been created by using php also)

Tags: php, select, drop-down-menu

I am trying to get the option selected by the user by using PHP (failing in that) where the dropdown itself contains the names of the tables and has been generated using PHP. This is my code for dropdown and grabbing its value:

Edited version of the code:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{

//This code is to show all the tables in database ecommerce having word "brand" in it
$query = "SHOW TABLES FROM ecommerce LIKE '%_brand'";
$runQuery = mysql_query($query);
echo "<form method='post' action='#'>";
echo "<select name='mee'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($runQuery))
    echo "<option value='something'>".$row[0]."</option>";
echo "</select>";
echo "</form>";
$var = $_POST["mee"];
echo $var;
}
```

this is the error:

```
Undefined index: mee in C:\......
```

Comment: Is the `method` attribute of your `<form>` set to "post"? We need to see more code. (Plus your `<option>` tag is missing the `value` attribute here.)

Comment: Option value attribute is missing

Comment: What is $ROW[0]? is it a string or a number?

Comment: try $row["0"] , use quotes if you are getting a string from the Db.

Comment: tried that too but the thing is code is working fine until the second last line:$var = $_POST["mee"];

Comment: Why do you display the form only if it has been submited? Can we see more code?

Comment: And 1 last thing, you should use a conditional statement on $var, this is being called unconditionally even when you didnt press the submit btn, this is the cause of problem in your coding

Comment: Do you have a submit button, inside your form tags?? If not try adding a submit button

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the option tag.

```
<option value="something ">.$row[0].</option>
```

Maybe you are missing option value

Comment: well, I have changed the code and added 2 things (which should be added before I think)...One is the <form> tags (Did not do that before) and the second is value attribute....Editing the post now....please have a look

Answer (score 1):

Add values to options. You're adding values from database to options in that way that user can see the value when selecting. But you don't set value of each option, so when you send selected option it will use value of option and send it with post method.

```
echo "<option value='".$row[0]."'>something that user see</option>"
```

Comment: well, I have changed the code and added 2 things (which should be added before I think)...One is the <form> tags (Did not do that before) and the second is value attribute....Editing the post now....please have a look